# get tag attribute from html using find

Tags: php, find

i have this html code

```
  <img alt="Tablet - BLUE"
       title="Tablet - BLUE" src="helo.jpg" normal-src="helo_norm.jpg">
```

I use php find() to get the src helo.jpg text of img tag. It works. How can i get the normal-src helo_norm.jpg text?

```
 foreach($html->find('img') as $ul)
            {
                    $picturelink=$ul->src;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use...

```
$normalSrc = $ul->{'normal-src'};
```

Comment: an explanation of what the code is doing would improve this answer.